# Fixing TypeError from NNjoin plugin on QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, typeerror

When I try to use the plugin NNjoin on QGIS resulting this message:

> TypeError: setValue(self, int): argument 1 has unexpected type
> 'float'

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Hi this typically means that the values that you are setting into the method, in this case a float, is not the data type that it expected. setValue is expecting an int. floats and ints are not the same. You can try casting the float -- int(float), or not using a float is this is a pre-canned method.

Comment: https://github.com/havatv/qgisnnjoinplugin/issues/32

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug. [`setValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qprogressbar.html#value-prop) expects `int` value. But in `NNJoin_plugin.py` file it takes `0.0` which is `float`.

For a temporary solution:

1. Go to the plugin folder (Settings > User Profiles > Open Active Profile Folder, and navigate to `python\plugins\NNJoin`)
2. In file `NNJoin_plugin.py` (Line 137) and `NNJoin_gui.py` (Line 224), change `0.0` to `0`.
3. Restart QGIS.

Comment: Is that all the changes required? [This fork](https://github.com/havatv/qgisnnjoinplugin/commit/d68fa17a9b0ce7a2819e461a5b274536f13df2c3) made a few more.

Comment: @user2856 You are right. I missed the other setValue method.